# SSLError SSLCertVerificationError issue on Debian Server

Tags: python, ssl, pip, debian

I get the SSL error when I 'pip install' my environment installed by miniconda3 on my Debian server.

Previously, I was able to install pip through this environment.

Error as below:

```
Collecting pdfkit
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify fa
iled: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /packages/64/1b/26c080096dd93936dccfd32c682bed3d5630a84aae9d493ff68afb2ae0fb/pdfkit-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify fa
iled: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /packages/64/1b/26c080096dd93936dccfd32c682bed3d5630a84aae9d493ff68afb2ae0fb/pdfkit-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

The First attempts, I tried to setup with `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`. So, I downloaded the `get-pip.py` and compile that script with python. The result returned 'The page you have requested has been blocked, because the URL is banned.'. I think banning it could be Fortinet or FortiGuard.

Secondly, I downloaded pip whl file from `https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files`. And also, I installed the `.whl` file. So, it didn't work.

P.S. I don't any UI platform for this server. It has only CLI.

What should I do?

Thanks,

Comment: Based on your description there is some firewall restricting access in your environment. Talk to whoever manages this firewall on how you need to setup your environment so that it plays well with the firewall. Or maybe they need to do some adjustments to the firewall setup. Or maybe what you are trying to do should not be done in the first place based on some IT policy.